# make sure txt file has a certain text

Tags: php

I have got this script:

`$counter = file_get_contents(strtolower($_GET["username"]).".txt") - 1;`

I want the "1" to change to this:

`echo $_GET["amount"];`

I want that script to run if the allocated txt file `<?php echo $_GET["username"];?>.txt` has enough in it.

For example, if the txt file has "8" in it, and `echo $_GET["amount"];` was equal to 7, the txt file has enough in it. But if the txt file has "6.05" in it, and `echo $_GET["amount"];` was equal to 7, the txt file doesn't have enough in it.

How can I do this?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? From the question it sounds basic.

Comment: First of all post your code, second, what? Can you re-write your question to directly address the problem, are you trying to compare two strings?

Comment: You're using a textfile database? Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: So you basically want to know if `$_GET["amount"] <= (file_get_contents("{$_GET[username]}.txt") + 1)`?

Comment: Side note: Any special reason you're not using an actual database for this?  Text files are a lot of work.

Comment: 1. I am having trouble with 2 things. I am struggling to change the "1" to the variable in the url (?amount=7). 2. That is my code. 3. I will try to rewrite. 4. I am trying to make 1 line of code to not run if amount in txt file is smaller than the variable in the url (?amount=7). 5. Whats wrong with using a textdatabase? 6. sorry, I dont understand your question. 7. I cant use an actual database for multiple reasons.

Comment: So you want this:? `$counter = file_get_contents($_GET['username'] . '.txt');$counter = intval($counter); $counter -= $_GET['amount'];`?

Comment: To get the amount in get WITH username just append `&amount=7`

Comment: How do a append?

Comment: Just add it in the end...

Comment: Phillip, `$counter = file_get_contents($_GET['username'] . '.txt');$counter = intval($counter); $counter -= $_GET['amount'];` just keeps setting the file to 0

Comment: I mean, I dont understand many php terms.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you wouldn't get the variable from the url. `$counter = intval(file_get_contents(strtolower($_GET["username"]).".txt")) - $_GET['amount'];`

Comment: no problem. still keeps resetting to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `amount` as parameter into your url, it should be something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/path?username=jhon&amount=1"></a>
                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Or if the `amount` is a variable:

```
$username = 'jhon'
$amount = 6;

echo '<a href="http://example.com/path?username='. $username .'&amount='. $amount .'"></a>';
```

Then you can get the amount like this:

```
$counter = file_get_contents(strtolower($_GET["username"]).".txt") - $_GET["amount"];

if ($counter > 0) {
    // file has enough
} else {
    // file doesn't has enough
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, What do you mean by interchangeable ?

Comment: The numbers for example `$amount = 6;` or `if ($counter > 0) {`, can they change to like 4.5 or 2.05 (same for username).